# How to continously run the cron job for bulk of 5000 users

Tags: php, cron

I have the database of 5000 users.Already there is cron job running of Once in A Week.
Initially when users were among 100's things was working fine. Now when users reached to 5000 then what happening is Cron job starts to run for some 500-600 users and breaks down. I researched it and came to the conclusion that since HTTP follow stateless protocol, so whenever any new request comes then cron job break down in between. Now my question is How can I be able to run the Cron Job for all 5000 users without break down. Please help me.

Comment: create batches .. Like run for 0-100 first .. 100-200 second and so on..

Comment: then It will be like I would required to created n no of crons.. @Confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would firstly check your PHP error logs as you may be hitting time and memory limits. If you are performing database queries I would also check the logs to see if any limits are being hit.

**PHP Memory Limit Increase**

Increasing the memory limit will allow your script to run for longer if it currently running out of memory.

***Option One***

Update your php.ini file. Change 256 to suit your requirements.

```
php_value memory_limit 256MB
```

***Option Two***

Add [ini_set('memory_limit', nM)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to increase the memory limit, again change 256 to suit your requirements:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

**PHP Execution Limit Increase**

Add [set_time_limit(n)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to your PHP file to increase the current execution timeout (changing 300 to suit your requirements):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

**Split Up Database Results (Batches)**

If you are performing a query that returns a large number of rows, it could be timing out. You can try implementing the following example logic, which splits a big query into smaller chunks using limit and offset.

```
// Get total rows count
$total_rows = SELECT count(id) FROM users;

// Set a block size
$block_size   = 300;

// Init starting offset
$block_offset = 0;

for($block = $block_offset; $block < $total_rows; $block = $block + $block_size) {

  // Query
  $data = SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $block_size OFFSET $block_offset;

  // Loop through each row and process here
  foreach($data as $row) {
    .. code here

    // You can also echo out something here so script is returning some data. Sometimes if nothing is sent back for a while it can cause issues (not generally for a cron though) e.g.
    echo 'Done block ' . $block;
  }

  // Update block offset, so offset increments by block size (300)  
  $block_offset = $block_offset + $block_size ;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Springie I will try this.

Comment: Let us know if it works and it does accept as the answer